# « Ça fait longtemps que ... {passé composé} » vs « Ça faisait longtemps que ... {plus-que-parfait} »

Tags: temps-grammatical

***Dernière mise à jour : août 2017 :***

« Ça fait longtemps que / Il y a longtemps que ... {plus-que-parfait} » :

> Ça **fait** longtemps que je ne **m’étais** pas **empiffré** comme ça.
>
> {ou bien}: Il y **a** longtemps que je ne **m’étais** pas **empiffré** comme ça.

Je viens de tomber sur cette construction de phrase, un mélange des deux ci-dessous. On utilise celle-ci dans quelle situation,  par rapport aux deux autres ?

---

« Ça fait longtemps que ... {passé composé} » :

> 1) Ça **fait** longtemps que je ne **me suis** pas **empiffré**.

« Ça faisait longtemps que ... {plus-que-parfait} » :

> 2) Ça **faisait** longtemps que je ne **m’étais** pas **empiffré** comme ça.

À ce que je crois comprendre :

La 1<sup>ère</sup> phrase : quand on vient juste de se gaver à un buffet à volonté, au point de ne pas pouvoir avaler une bouchée de plus ?

La 2<sup>ème</sup> phrase : quand on est sur le point de commencer à manger copieusement ?

Comment: Je ne dirais pas « Ça fait longtemps que ... {plus-que-parfait} ». Ça ne me semble pas logique.

Comment: @Laure « Ça ***fait*** bien longtemps qu’ils ***auraient dû*** disparaître du village. » vs « Ça ***faisait*** bien longtemps qu’ils ***auraient dû*** disparaître du village. » "they should have disappeared": I suppose this makes for an interesting exception where plus-que-parfait is required in any case, regardless of whether you use « fait » or « faisait »?

Comment: But ***auraient dû*** is ***conditionnel passé***  and so this last sentence in your comment quite normal.  Whereas *Ça fait longtemps que je ne m’**étais pas empiffré*** is plus-que parfait, quite another story for me. In the sentence in your comment using *ça fait* or *ça faisait* places *qu'ils auraient dû disparaître du village* on a different place on the timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est quasiment ça, avec une petite nuance sur la 2eme phrase. Cette expression exprime une longue période pendant laquelle on n'a pas fait quelque chose.

Au passé, l'attente est terminée, donc on vient de faire ce dont on parle.

Au présent, l'attente n'est pas terminée. On peut le dire juste avant de faire ce dont on parle, mais pas forcément. C'est même plus souvent utilisé quand on y pense mais qu'on n'est pas sur le point de le faire. Par exemple, on passe devant un buffet à volonté et on se dit "Tiens, ça fait longtemps que je me suis pas empiffré...".

Personnellement, ça m'arrive même d'utiliser "*faisait*" juste avant, mais quand je suis sûr de faire la chose. Dans la file d'attente du cinéma, ou en entrant dans le restaurant par exemple. On a passé le point de non retour donc on peut considérer que l'attente est bel est bien terminée.

Comment: je ne saisissais pas  tout à fait la nuance entre les deux, mais eurêka ! Merci, reçu 5 sur 5 ! :)

Comment: Hey, buddy. Just this evening, I was eating Baked Curry (or 焼きカレー in Japanese) with my girlfriend in a Japanese restaurant, and we both realised that we couldn't come up with a good French translation for it. How do you call this food in France? And is it popular to begin with? :D

Comment: http://osumituki.com/event/moshimo/55826.html

Comment: @Alone-zee Hmmm "Gratin au curry" peut-être ? La façon dont c'est présenté, dans un plat carré et tout, ça me rappelle un gratin.

Comment: Le "gratin au curry", c'est ce qui s'en rapproche le plus, je vois. :D

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de différence entre :

```
Il y a (un temps) que...
Cela fait (un temps) que...
Voici (un temps) que...
```

où *(un temps)* peut être remplacé par *deux ans*, *deux heures*, *longtemps*, etc.
Après, vous pouvez écrire :

> Il y a (un temps) que je ne me suis pas empiffré.

C'est un constat, présent de l'indicatif. Ni bien, ni mal.

> Il y a (un temps) que je ne m'étais pas empiffré.

La proposition principale est au présent, la subordonnée à l'imparfait. Cela (s'empiffrer) vient de se produire.

> Il y avait (un temps) que je m'étais pas empiffré.

La principale est au passé. Elle peut faire référence à un "empiffrage" récent, certes, mais pas forcément :

> A cette époque j'étais jeune, il y avait (un temps) que je ne m'étais
>   pas empiffré et j'ai tout rendu.

C'est généreux :)

Answer (score 1):

La différence vient de l'emploi du temps, et non d'une expression particulière :

> **Le passé composé** exprime une action passée achevée:
>
> - Une action passée dont l'effet dure encore quand on en parle:
>
>   > *J'ai cru que ces médicaments la calmeraient.*
> - Une vérité générale:
>
>   > *De tout temps l'homme a été un loup pour l'homme.*
>
> **Le plus-que-parfait** exprime une action passée, achevée, d'une durée plutôt longue et antérieure à une autre action passée:
>
> > *L'homme reconnut qu'il avait fait une bêtise.*

-- D'après [FrançaisFacile.com](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-8681.php)

---

Ta première phrase dénote qu'on vient de s'empiffrer.

La seconde est un constat simple, on ne s'est pas empiffré pendant une certaine période.

Answer (score 0):

Teleporting Goat said it all:

> Ça **fait** longtemps que je ne me **suis** pas empiffré.

**Present**: *I am waiting*, a frustration.

> Ça **faisait** longtemps que je ne m’**étais** pas empiffré comme ça.

**Past**: *I have been waiting*, refers to a current or recent action, a relief.

---

The alternative is just a more spoken form ("faire" vs "être"), but the decisive bit is the *presence of past tense*, the same rule should apply:

> Il y *a* longtemps que je ne m’**étais** pas empiffré comme ça.

> Il y *avait* longtemps que je ne m’**étais** pas empiffré comme ça.